# Android Notification Listener duplicate hell

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications

Need a little help - this is doing my head in!

I'm the Dev of ReadItToMe, an app that reads out your messages and lets you reply by voice.
The issue I've been facing and hacking around the last year has been duplicate notifications.  I'll use WhatsApp as an example.

If I get a single WhatsApp notification, happy days, it's one notification.  If I get another from a different chat.. I get one group notification, the previous unread chat notification with a new post time so you can't check if it's from the past and then the new notification.

Solutions I've tried:

- Keeping a list of notifications read by creating a hash code of notifications using their title, message and package name when they arrive and then removing them from the list when their dismissed (onNotificationRemoved).. But whatdya know!  In the above scenario all notifications are removed and then resent so this solution is useless.

  - Comparing timestamps, which doesn't work as the duplicate notifications have new timestamps
  - Comparing keys/ids, these never change for a chat so they're not unique to a single notification of a message
  - Many others I've forgotten
  - Checking if the notification is a group to at least ignore that, doesn't work because the first notification is always a group.  It's only when there's multiple notifications that the "group" is actually a group with content like "2 new messages".

Does anyone know of any way or can think of any creative solution to accurately determine (80% accuracy would do) which notifications are genuinely new and which have been previously posted?
Or is this just fundamentally broken on Android...

Comment: "then removing them from the list when their dismissed (onNotificationRemoved)." - why to remove, you can store it in db, lets say last 12 hrs and clear only records older than X hrs?

Comment: The reason being, if an identical message is sent again intentionally i.e. someone sends "lol" again across the course of that 12 hour period, it'll be treated as a duplicate message when it's actually a legitimate new message.  Appreciate the response though.  (btw this is my old account, I'm waiting to get them merged )

Comment: Having kinda the same problem now...

Comment: Hi Rob, may I know what is solution you found for this problem. Even i am stuck at this similar issue. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I fixed it on this way, you can to use the "when" attribute combined with the saved-way using when:

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {    
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - sbn.getNotification().when > 3000 ||
                isInArray(sbn.getNotification().when)) {
            //when != sbn.getPostTime()
            //If notification is 3 seconds old, it is discarted
            return;
        } else {
            //Else, push to the array of notifications "when-id" to compare next time
            goNextPosition(sbn.getNotification().when);
        }
... next part of code
}
```

> long when
>   A timestamp related to this notification, in milliseconds since the epoch. Default value: Now. Choose a timestamp that will be most relevant to the user. For most finite events, this corresponds to the time the event happened (or will happen, in the case of events that have yet to occur but about which the user is being informed). Indefinite events should be timestamped according to when the activity began.
>
> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#when

If someone has this problem, feel free to ask me, I'm sorry, I'm spanish native.

Comment: What is that isInArray ?? is that method name ? how to implement that method inside if loop. can you please publish the entire code ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, duplicate push notification try this :

first : remove all duplicate application from your device, in my case  i had 3 same application.

second : reinstall that application but try to change the package name, it's work for me. good luck

Comment: welcome to SO.  not sure this answers the OP's question.  see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer